# How to get special day of week and list of weekdays using bootstrap datepicker in PHP

Tags: php, jquery, datepicker, bootstrap-datepicker, bootstrap-daterangepicker

I'm using Bootstrap datepicker and I'd like to get special days of every week ( Like: Monday, Wednesday, Saturday). For example, If we select every monday and Wednesday then select only Monday and Wednesday.

And I want this weekday through month wise, (Like, If we select date 24-jun  to 24-july and select only Monday. Then every Monday from 24-jun to 24-july will be selected).

So what would be the correct way to get weekdays using bootstrap datepicker?

Any kind of help would be highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I´ve found the solution :

```
 $start_date = "28-06-2016";
 $end_date = "28-07-2016";
 $weekdays = [1,2]; // 0 = sunday, 1 = monday ...

 $range_date = array();
 for ($i = strtotime($start_date); $i <= strtotime($end_date); $i = strtotime('+1 day', $i)) 
 {
     if(in_array(date('N', $i), $weekdays))//Monday == 1
     {
           echo date('l Y-m-d', $i).'<br>'; //prints the date only if it's a Monday or tuseday etc..
      }
 }
```

And output :

```
 Tuesday 2016-06-28
 Monday 2016-07-04
 Tuesday 2016-07-05
 Monday 2016-07-11
 Tuesday 2016-07-12
 Monday 2016-07-18
 Tuesday 2016-07-19 
 Monday 2016-07-25
 Tuesday 2016-07-26
```